# Error While formating a mysql statement which includes a regular expression

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

Am trying to retrieve data from a Mysql table i get an error while applying string formatting techniques

First try, results an error

1.service= "Dynamic value"

```
st="SELECT Name FROM servicetable WHERE hsubservices={0} and Contact REGEXP '[A-Z]{2}|Texas|\s[0-9]{5}'".format(service)
```

The error which occured here is Index out of range for tuple , yes i get it the '{}' in regular expression are being considered as values of tuple

2. service="Dynamic Value"

error=mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Value and Contact REGEXP '[A-Z]{2}|Texas|\s[0-9]{5}''

`st="SELECT DoctorsName FROM dev_healthservices WHERE hsubservices= %s and Contact REGEXP '[A-Z]{2}|Texas|\s[0-9]{5}'"%(service)`

```
mydb=mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "",
    user = "",
    passwd = "",
    database = ""
)

mycursor=mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute(st)
```

Comment: Don't use string interpolation... use placeholders in your query and supply then as arguments to `execute`...

Comment: eg: does something like: `st = 'select DoctorsName from dev_healthservices WHERE hsubservices = %s and Contact REGEXP %s'` then`mycursor.execute(st, (service, '[A-Z]{2}|Texas|\s[0-9]{5}'))` work?

Comment: Thanks , it worked @JonClements